# Preventing hashdeep from crossing mount points?

Tags: freebsd

Is there anyway of preventing hashdeep from traversing file systems?

I have my main zfs volume mounted within my (FreeBSD) tools jail, viz:

```
/mnt/VOLUME1/ian on /mnt/VOLUME1/jails/tools/mnt/ian (nullfs, local)
```

so, naturally, a hashdeep on /mnt/VOLUME1 is never going to end.

Any way to prevent that, other than unmounting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "bind mount" the top level, `/mnt/VOLUME1/ian`, to a different spot, then run `hashdeep` on it. E.g.,

```
mkdir /mnt/TMP
mount -o bind /mnt/VOLUME1/ian /mnt/TMP
```

The "bind mounted" directory tree does not include sub mounts of the source.
I suppose `man mount` can give some more details.

Comment: Thanks Ralph.  Turns out FreeBSD is a bit different:  "mount_nullfs" is what I needed there.